# How do I create a component instance programmatically in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

I need to create a vue 3 component instance programmatically. I'm trying to do so in a directive. I get the error, 'tooltip is not a constructor'.

Here is the relevant part of my directive code:

```
import tooltip from './tooltip.vue'; // component that I want an instance of

export const tooltipDirective = {
  beforeMount(el: any, binding: any, vnode: any) {
    ...
    const _tooltip = new tooltip(); // error - tooltip is not a constructor
    ...
  },
};
```

And here is my tooltip component (.vue file):

```
export default {
  name: 'tooltip',
  props: [
    'tooltipTxt',
    'tooltipPos',
  ],
  setup(props: any) {
    const lState: {isShowing: boolean} = reactive({
      isShowing: false
    });

    let positionClasses: string;
    switch (props.tooltipPos) {
      case tooltipPos.lt:
        positionClasses = 'right-1 bottom-1';
        break;
      case tooltipPos.rt:
        positionClasses = 'left-1 bottom-1';
        break;
      case tooltipPos.lb:
        positionClasses = 'right-1 top-1';
        break;
      default:
        positionClasses = 'left-1 top-1';
        break;
    }

    return {
      lState,
      props,
      positionClasses
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score -3):

The reason why it does not work is because your component has no real constructor or class. Therefore, you cannot create an instance of this component.

But there is a workaround for that.

```js
const TooltipClass = Vue.extend(tooltip);
const tooltipInstance = new TooltipClass()
```

`Vue.extend` creates a subclass of the Vue constructor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've seen examples of your suggestion working in vue, version 2. I tried to: Import Vue from 'vue' and 'extend' as you suggest, but in vue, version 3, I'm getting the error: 'cannot  read property of undefined'.

Comment: It seems like that `extend` got removed from the api completely. What do you want to do exactly?  Have you tried it with the class api?

Comment: Just trying to be clever - wanted to save myself creating my tooltip using the html dom ie. create an instance of a vue component and then get the dom for that component from the vue component instance (via $el). I have reverted to using the html dom api in my directive, to create my tooltip. I have an aversion to using classes since I left the c-sharp world :-). Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem! I found a library for that use case: https://github.com/hekigan/vue-directive-tooltip/tree/master/src/directives Maybe the code can help there :)